# Can not assign to pair in a map

Tags: dictionary, go

I have the following pair defined in my go program

```
type pair struct {
  a float64
  b float64
}
```

Then I create a map:

```
dictionary map[string]pair
```

I first add one element:

```
dictionary["xxoo"] = pair{5.0, 2.0}
```

Then I am trying to do this:

```
dictionary["xxoo"].b = 5.0  // try to change from 2.0 to 5.0
```

The last line doesn't compile and it said "can not assign to it"

I want to know what's the reason for this?

Comment: Out of curiosity: do you also expect a programming language to have a predefined type for a triple -- a tuple of three elements? Four? `N`? What is so special about *a pair?*

Comment: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/3117

Answer (score 6):

In order to assign a value to a struct field, that struct must be "addressable". Addressability is covered in the ["Address Operators"](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Address_operators) section of the language specification.

Map values aren't addressable to leave map implementations the freedom to move values around in memory as needed. Because map values aren't addressable, you you can't use a selector (`.`) operator on the value to assign to the struct field. If you use a pointer type as the map value, i.e. `map[string]*pair`, the pointer indirection satisfies the addressability requirement.

```
dict := make(map[string]*pair)
dict["xxoo"] = &pair{5.0, 2.0}
dict["xxoo"].b = 5.0
```

If you are working with values, you need to copy the existing value via assignment, or supply an entirely new value:

```
dict := make(map[string]pair)
dict["xxoo"] = pair{5.0, 2.0}

// copy the value, change one field, then reassign
p := dict["xxoo"]
p.b = 5.0
dict["xxoo"] = p

// or replace the value in full
dict["xxoo"] = pair{5.0, 5.0}
```

Comment: To possibly make this answer a bit better: the values stored in a map are not addressable because the map implementations are free to move the values they store in memory in arbitrary ways. This is required for many approaches to implementing maps effectively.  If values may move in memory, you can't return a pointer to such a value.

Comment: @kostix: I was trying to avoid the map implementation details, which are another toppic, but I guess it doesn't hurt to mention it.

Answer (score 3):

That's not legal for reasons described [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/6IaQ1H8ewMk):

> Querying a map give a copy of the stored item, so there is no point assigning to it.

The recommended workaround is:

```
var xxoo = dictionary["xxoo"]
xxoo.b = 5.0
dictionary["xxoo"] = xxoo
```

Answer (score 2):

It's forbidden as said in Thomas' answer. Use pointers instead.

```
dict := map[string]*pair{}
dict["xxoo"] = &pair{5.0, 2.0}
fmt.Println(dict["xxoo"].b) // 2
dict["xxoo"].b = 5.0
fmt.Println(dict["xxoo"].b) // 5
```

https://play.golang.org/p/nEr_WrQOly